# How can I play an mp3 in Windows Phone game with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, sharpdx

How can I play an mp3 in Windows Phone game? MediaPlayer is not an option as it stops the music when I play sound effects on top. XNA is also not an option as it's already discontinued by Microsoft. I've searched all over the net, but can't find a SharpDX sample for playing mp3.

Comment: Since my game is in HTML5, and WebAudio is not supported, I resorted to  C# function calls for Audio. However, WP WebView supports HTML5Audio, so as a not elegant workaround atm I play .mp3 music via SoundJS, and play .wav sound effects with external c# calls to XAudio2 (SharpDX).

Comment: Can you play a wav file or must it be an MP3 file

Comment: It must be any compressed file format. WAV will be too big if I decompress it.